# Dynamic data and dynamic types in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design, bigdata

We need to develop a program for monitoring some devices and etc on network, but we don't need any hard coded device or transfer protocol or parameter types in program.

We want the user to be able to define parameters (Name, Alias, DataType, Group, Transfer Protocol, IP, sampling time and ...) and bind this parameters to parameter group. And finally bind parameter group to user defined device.

Any time the user can define new parameters, new devices and and ... .

How can I design the necessary SQL Server tables?

Generate separate tables at runtime for parameters? Store all parameters as string or as XML? Any sample?

We talk about 100 devices, 100 parameters for any devices and very fast sampling time.

Comment: You could store properties as EAV, or as xml, or as json. None of these options are optimal, but they are all very flexible. I think I would probably go with json since it's the easiest to work with in c#.

Comment: It looks like you only need FAST for storage and not retrieval. Then store data in one table.  Multiple tables only have an reducing data size.  For example the Name and Alias will be common so you do not need to save both every time.  So you have a table of Alias and Name.  Then in your results you save only one, but then you have to lookup to make sure the Name/Alias is in the table.  For speed, you do not want to do any look-ups.

Comment: If the schema is completely fluid in runtime, as is suggested when you say "Any time the user can define new parameters, new devices and and ... .",
perhaps you should consider a Document database like MongoDb instead. you would in this case use json instead of xml of course.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is more a question of the real world requirements, not a question of database design in my eyes:

- Who need to change this data how often?
- And how skilled are these users?

If these configurations has to be changed seldom by it pros or admins I would consider this in e.g. App.config as xml.

But if you have more inexperienced user and they have to update this configs often I would recommend to provide a user ui form with all checks for errors. Therefore it could be easier to store all informations in a sql db table.

For 100 devices a xml config seems hard to maintain.